# Why is ^M added to the last line of an output file written in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

This is the file I have, a.tsv

```
ENST00000330436 chr4    -       96099729        96125021
ENST00000332884 chr4    -       96518062        96549623
ENST00000651514 chr5    -       145620969       145647819
ENST00000550308 chr17   +       32532671        32551233
ENST00000371270 chr4    -       96294895        96343068^M
```

I used this Python 2.7 script

```
with open(a.tsv, 'wb') as f_output:
    tsv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\n')
    tsv_output.writerow(output_unique)
```

to generate the above a.tsv file. I see there is `^M` at the end of the last line in the file.

Where do I make changes in the above codeto remove that?

An example of the list is:

```
output_unique=[string1, string2, string3]
```

Comment: Seems to work fine on my machine. Which os version are you using? Can you try :set list on vi to view the non-printable characters?

Comment: I see, there is ^M character on the last line at the end of line. Can you tell me what does that mean and how do I remove adding of that character in the Python code above?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash. Your input file uses DOS line endings (CRLF), but `awk` assumes POSIX line endings (LF only).

Comment: Can you please tell me, how do I change that, in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Your TSV files uses DOS line endings (CRLF), while `awk` expects POSIX line endings. The problem is that you are writing multiple rows using a single call to `writerow`; as far as your Python code is concerned, it generated a single row that uses `\n` to delimit the *fields*. The single row ends with `\r\n`, but `awk` sees it as a TSV file whose last row has its last field end with `\r`.

The Python code should be something like

```
output_unique = [
    ['ENST00000330436', 'chr4', '-', '96099729', '96125021'],
    ['ENST00000332884', 'chr4', '-', '96518062', '96549623'],
    ['ENST00000651514', 'chr5', '-', '145620969', '145647819'],
    ['ENST00000371270', 'chr4', '-', '96294895', '96343068'],
]

with open("a.tsv", 'w') as f_output:
    tsv_output = csv.write(f_output, delimiter='\t')
    tsv_output.writerows(output_unique)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I forgot to mention about how output_unique list looks like, it has something like, `output_unique=[string1, string2, string3]`. The above code, does not work for something like this, it does not add a newline by the end of each row.